# How to read file from root directory on Android without getExternalStorageDirectory()?

Tags: android, android-studio, deprecated

`getExternalStorageDirectory()` method is deprecated on Android. On every tutorial and 
stackoverflow question people reads file from root with `getExternalStorageDirectory()`

I tried to use `getExternalFilesDir()` but that method gives me my package path.

How can I get the path of root without `getExternalStorageDirectory()`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The root is "/".

Comment: "How can I get the path of root without getExternalStorageDirectory()?" -- you can't. Moreover, you cannot access the root of external storage on Android 10 (by default) and Android R+ (for all apps). Use something else, such as `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` and the rest of the Storage Access Framework.